# Getting error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, next.js, runtime-error

app.js

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import { Thirdwebeb3Provider } from "@3rdweb/hooks";
const supportedChainIds = [4];
const connectors = {
     injected: {},
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Thirdwebeb3Provider supportedChainIds={supportedChainIds} connectors={connectors}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Thirdwebeb3Provider>
  )
}
export default MyApp
```

I am using React version 17

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Please do not add "help please" to your question titles in order to avoid the duplicate title detector. This was triggered when you wrote your question. It really is worth your reading [some of the duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Element+type+is+invalid%3A+expected+a+string+%28for+built-in+components%29+or+a+class%2Ffunction+%28for+composite+components%29+but+got%3A+undefined) - they could well help you faster than receiving a (possibly duplicate) answer.

Comment: It doesn't look like the error comes from the provided code. Make sure you're importing/exporting all your React components properly across your codebase.